# Why does a call to write(3) terminate the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, pthreads

I have a thread that saves to a file. This works fine probably more than 99.9% of the time. Sometimes, though, the thread terminates unexpectedly in the same place every time, a call to `write()` (the BSD system call). The actual call to `write()` is very simple:

```
ssize_t wr = ::write(m_fd, buffer, (size_t)bytes);
```

At the time of the exit, the buffer is 4 bytes of zeros, bytes is 4, and the file descriptor is the same as all the previous writes made in this thread. I installed a clean-up function using pthread_cleanup_push() that is called from pthread_exit() so I can poke around in the debugger when this unexpected exit occurs.

The question is, why does `write()` do this at all instead of returning an error? Can I stop it from exiting and handle an error without causing the thread to terminate? The process continues seemingly unaffected, and there are a dozen other threads that seem to continue to function normally after this unexpected exit occurs. This is OS X 10.11.6.

I notice a call to `tramp_cerror()` that does not seem to be documented anywhere, in fact if you Google it nothing comes up anywhere at all. Am I the first person in the world to wonder what it does and why it seems empowered to terminate my thread?

This is the stack:

```
#0  0x01c1e388 in cleanup(void*) at ThreadAny.cpp:32
#1  0x0728900b in _pthread_exit ()
#2  0x07289adc in pthread_exit ()
#3  0x07286bc2 in _pthread_exit_if_canceled ()
#4  0x9189ed9d in cerror ()
#5  0x918a7415 in tramp_cerror ()
#6  0x13fda508 in 0x13fda508 ()
#7  0x024f6388 in long long Standard::File::write<unsigned int>(unsigned int const*, long long) at FileIO.h:54
#8  0x024e5fab in SaveFile(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >, bool, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >*) at SaveFile.cpp:4947
#9  0x01c1eeaa in SaveFileThread(void*) at ThreadAny.cpp:103
#10 0x01afe81d in PThread::execute() at PThread.cpp:129
#11 0x01ac7c95 in PThread::run() at POSIXThread.cpp:91
#12 0x01ac7d8a in PThread::threadFunction(void*) at POSIXThread.cpp:131
#13 0x07287928 in _pthread_body ()
#14 0x0728789e in _pthread_start ()
#15 0x07284f2e in thread_start ()
```

Comment: What compiler and what version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: `write()` is a cancellation point. So, if some other thread sends a cancellation request to this thread, then it's possible that the thread gets terminated and gives you the appearance that `write()` call terminated the thread. Can you check if any other thread sends a cancellation request?

Comment: The compiler version is:
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix